# Inner join followed by a self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, self-join

I have two tables `PERSON` and `PERSONRELATION`.

On the `PERSON`table I have the columns `PERSONpk`, `FIRSTNAME`, and `LASTNAME`.

On the `PERSONRELATION` table I have `MANAGER1fk` which is the a fk for `PERSONpk`.

I am trying to join the two tables, bring over all the fields above and self join back to add the `MANAGERFIRSTNAME` and `MANAGERLASTNAME`.  Here is what I have done but it apparently isn't correct:

```
Select PERSONpk, MANAGER1FK,e.FIRSTNAME,e.LastName,m.FIRSTNAME,M.LASTNAME
FROM dbo.PERSON e
INNER JOIN dbo.PERSONRELATION rel
ON rel.PERSONFK = PERSONPK
INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON m ON e.PERSONpk = m.MANAGER1FK
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: In your first join it looks like you are referencing the same column, you should probably use `rel.MANAGER1FK = e.PERSONPK` if I am understanding your schema.

Comment: The last join looks wrong.  person to person table isn't right on the join. 
 It should be `on m.personpk = rel.manager1fk`  rel contains both the employee and the manager Id based on your description at the top.

Comment: I don't think you need multiple tables for this. You should be able to accomplish the same thing with just a Manager1 key in the PERSON table, then join back to itself. This is a normal parent-child type query. As you've described, if you select e.PersonPK and rel.Manager1fk, it'll be the same number. Can you provide a data mock up or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues:

- Your last join was wrong (you were joining back to e when I believe you wnat to join rel.Manager1FK to m.  Think of it linearly...  I have an employee... an employee can have many relations... each relation is to another employee... and based on the column names, these relations are employee manager relations.  So you go from P-->REL-->M M--P can't exist w/o REL in your data example.
- You should alias e.personpk on the 2nd join
- given you have to reference person twice all columns from person must be aliased (even in the select)

Table personrelation contains the FK for both the employee and the manager to person; thus you need to join the 2nd fk field from personrelation (MANAGER1fk) (and this isn't a self join)  If the hierarchy were all maintained in person it would be a self join.

```
SELECT e.PERSONpk
     , rel.MANAGER1FK
     , e.FIRSTNAME
     , e.LastName
     , m.FIRSTNAME
     , M.LASTNAME
FROM dbo.PERSON e
INNER JOIN dbo.PERSONRELATION rel
  ON rel.PERSONFK = e.PERSONPK
INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON m 
  ON m.PERSONpk = rel.MANAGER1FK
```

Comment: Using INNER JOINs will eliminate the boss who doesn't have a boss. You _should_ be able to catch the boss with an INNER JOIN then LEFT OUTER JOIN.